# Как узнать тайм зону клиента

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py

Подскажите как можно в дискорде узнать тайм зону клиента, дабы команда бота работала корректно

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour >= 6 <= now.hour < 12:
        await ctx.send("утро")
    elif now.hour >= 12 <= now.hour < 18:
        await ctx.send("день")
    elif now.hour >= 18 <= now.hour < 23:
        await ctx.send("вечер")
    else:
        await ctx.send("ночь")
```